# Why can not update autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: codenameone

I am using two AutocompleteTextFilters as depended filters. I want the second one filter to change its options depending on the suggestion of the first filter.

I have bind an event listener on the first filter so as when it loose focus it triggers a proccess on the second filter.

The proble is that the second filter never changes its options. I even have setup hardcoded values in case somethig was wrong on my code but no luck.

The code I use is below:

```
public CreateSubmission(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance, Map<String, ProjectType> projectTypes) {
        this.projectTypes = projectTypes;
        initGuiBuilderComponents(resourceObjectInstance);
        gui_ac_projecttype.clear();
        gui_ac_projecttype.setCompletion( this.projectTypes.keySet().toArray( new String[0]) );
        gui_ac_projecttype.addFocusListener( new ProjectTypeFocusListener( this ));
        gui_ac_steps.setCompletion( new String[]{"t10", "t20"});

    }

    public void makeSteps (String selection) {
            ProjectType projectType = this.projectTypes.get( selection );
            if (projectType != null) {
                this.selectedProjectType = selection;

                int length = projectType.projectSteps.length;

                String[] steps = new String[ length ];
                for(int i =0; i < length; i ++) {
                    steps[i] = projectType.projectSteps[i].projectStep;
                }           

               // String[] s = gui_ac_steps.getCompletion();

                gui_ac_steps.setCompletion( new String[]{"t1", "t2"} );

                gui_ac_steps.repaint();
            }
            else {

            }

        }

public class ProjectTypeFocusListener implements FocusListener{
        private CreateSubmission parent;
        public ProjectTypeFocusListener( CreateSubmission parent ) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
        @Override
        public void focusGained(Component cmp) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(Component cmp) {
            this.parent.makeSteps (
                ((AutoCompleteTextField)cmp).getText()
            );

            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }
```

On the above code the initialization happens on "public CreateSubmission" method.
"gui_ac_projecttype" is the first AutocompletionTextField that triggers the whole proccess through it's FocusListener handler (class ProjectTypeFocusListener )

"gui_ac_steps" is the second AutocompleteTextField filter that must change its values. On the code above I initialize it's suggestions to "t10", "t20". Those two values are shown correctly.

Later from iside the FoculListenerHandler's method "ProjectTypeFocusListener.focusLost" I call method "makeSteps" which sets the suggestion options to "t1", "t2 and then I repaint the component. These two last values are never shown. It remains on the first values "t10", "t20".

The Strange thing is that in debugger when I ask  gui_ac_steps.getCompletion(); to see the current options ( the code that is commentd out into makeSteps method) I get the correct values "t1", "t2".

But on the screen it keeps showing "t10", "t20".

any help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything "important" in a focus listener. Especially not with a text field. They are somewhat unreliable because the text field switches to native editing and in effect transfers the focus there. The problem is that some events are delayed due to the back and forth with the native editing so by the time the focus event is received you've moved on to the next field.

Try something like this for this specific use case https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dynamic-autocomplete.html

Comment: Yes I have seen this link but my problem is that the second AutocmpleteTextField filter is depended on the first. So I need somehow to Listen to an Event that shows me that there has been a selection to the first filter. Then on the existing second filter I  have to change its options. On the link you suggested filter method is protected so I can not reference it from outside the class e.g en event listener, and I need somehow to listen to an event.  Is there any way to achieve my goal with this approach?

Comment: Use action listener on the first field. Filter is invoked internally dynamically. If you override it and implement the list there you will get invoked every time a user types. By the the first auto-complete would have already been filled